# How to know that Printer is not registered while using Google Cloud Print?

Tags: android, printing, google-cloud-print

I am using Google Cloud Print in my android application.
For that I have registered my printer on google cloud and while on printing command it gives me list of registered printers on google cloud for printing.

But, How can I give message like : "Please, Register your Printer on Google cloud",,, If user not registered his/her printer on cloud ?

That means, **How can I know that, there is no printer registered on Google Cloud Programmatically ?**

```
PrintHelper printHelper = new PrintHelper(QRCodeListActivity.this);
printHelper.setScaleMode(printHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
printHelper.printBitmap("Print Bitmap", result);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes , You can do it, Just make a call to **Search REST API** of Google cloud print.
**search API** = **https://www.google.com/cloudprint/search**.

It will return an object that contains the list of printers with details.Then you can parse that object , then you would know if any printer is registered or not. I have done using this way in AngularJS..

```
                        var data = {'connection_status': 'ALL', ticket: ''};
                            var req = {
                                method: 'POST',
                                url: 'https://www.google.com/cloudprint/search',
                                headers: {
                                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
                                },
                                params: data,
                            }

                            $http(req).then(function (data) {                                
                                success(data);                               
                            }, function (data) {                                
                                error(data);
                            });
```

And don't forget that , you must have a valid token..